# Image Caching – How to control when images are disposed?

Tags: swift, caching, kingfisher

I need to cache images on disk but to limit them say to 20 images. I am trying `Nuke` library. When I run

```
Nuke.loadImage(with: url, options: options, into: imageView)
```

image is cached as long as I am inside my View Controller. When I leave the views, next time images are being fetched again. So how do I make `Nuke` (or other lib) save those images for specific image count or time.

Before trying `Nuke` I was just saving images to Documents folder of the app every time I fetch image. I am sure there is a better way.

Update: I was able to do it with `Kingfisher`.

```
func getFromCache(id: String) {
    ImageCache.default.retrieveImage(forKey: id, options: nil) {
        image, cacheType in

        if let image = image {
            self.galleryImageView.image = image  
        } else {
            print("Not exist in cache.")
            self.loadImage()
        }
    }
}

private func loadImage() {            
    ImageDownloader.default.downloadImage(with: url, options: [], progressBlock: nil) {
        (image, error, url, data) in

        if let image = image {
            self.galleryImageView.image = image
            ImageCache.default.store(image, forKey: id, toDisk: true)
        }
    }
}
```

If I understand correctly, first `retrieveImage` fetches images from disk cache. Later from memory cache. And it frees them only when memory warning received. I hope it does. God help us.

Comment: You should check this lib https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Comment: AlamofireImage library offers pretty good image caching functionality https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage

Answer (score 1):

There are several advanced options for image caching. You can get a direct access to `Memory Cache` (default Nuke's `ImagePipeline` has two cache layers):

```
// Configure cache
ImageCache.shared.costLimit = 1024 * 1024 * 100 // Size in MB
ImageCache.shared.countLimit = 20 // You may use this option for your needs 
ImageCache.shared.ttl = 90 // Invalidate image after 90 sec

// Read and write images
let request = ImageRequest(url: url)
ImageCache.shared[request] = image
let image = ImageCache.shared[request]

// Clear cache
ImageCache.shared.removeAll()
```

Also, use `ImagePreheater` class. Preheating (a.k.a. prefetching) means loading images ahead of time in anticipation of their use. `Nuke` lib provides an `ImagePreheater` class that does just that:

```
let preheater = ImagePreheater(pipeline: ImagePipeline.shared)

let requests = urls.map {
    var request = ImageRequest(url: $0)
    request.priority = .low
    return request
}

// User enters the screen:
preheater.startPreheating(for: requests)

// User leaves the screen:
preheater.stopPreheating(for: requests)
```

You can use `Nuke` lib in combination with `Preheat` library which automates preheating of content in `UICollectionView` and `UITableView`. On iOS 10.0 and above you might want to use new prefetching APIs provided by iOS instead.